# Pipes equivalent code for simple functions

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Let's say, I have the following types:

```
type LinkID = Int

data Link = Link {
  lid :: LinkID,
  llength :: Int
  }

data Snap = Snap {
  slid :: LinkID,
  slength :: Int
  }
```

Now, I want to write a pipes based function which does this:

```
getSnaps :: LinkID -> [Link] -> [Snap] -> [(LinkID, [Snap])]
getSnaps l lks snp = map (\x -> (lid x, filter (\y -> lid x == slid y) snp)) a
  where a = filter (\x -> lid x > l) lks
```

Assumming that I already have Producers of `Link` and `Snap`, how can I implement the above `getSnaps` function in the Pipes world from these two Producers:

```
psnap :: Producer Snap IO ()
psnap = undefined

plink :: Producer Link IO ()
plink = undefined
```

The actual types of `psnap` and `plink` are more involved (created out by using attoparsec-pipes), but I would like to know how to implement the functionality of getSnaps from `psnap` and `plink`. Is there a proper way to solve this type of problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with is pretty similar to your code.  I just replaced `map` with `Pipes.Prelude.map` and one of the filters with `Pipes.Prelude.filter`:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes

type LinkID = Int

data Link = Link
    { lid :: LinkID
    , llength :: Int
    }

data Snap = Snap
    { slid :: LinkID
    , slength :: Int
    }

getSnaps
    :: Monad m
    => LinkID
    -> Producer  Link            m ()
    -> Producer  Snap            m ()
    -> Producer (LinkID, [Snap]) m ()
getSnaps l lks snp = do
    snp' <- lift (Pipes.toListM snp)  -- Cache `snp` into the list `snp'`
    lks >-> Pipes.filter (\x -> lid x > l)
        >-> Pipes.map (\x -> (lid x, filter (\y -> lid x == slid y) snp'))
```

Note that there is one non-trivial part, which is that the above solution strictly loads the `snp` `Producer`'s contents into the list `snp'`.  The reason for this is that we have to use the contents of the list repeatedly, so we need to cache the entire list in memory for repeated usage.